# Bag of words representation using sklearn plus Snowballstemmer

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, nltk

I have a list with songs, something like

```
list2 = ["first song", "second song", "third song"...]
```

Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words=stopwords.words('english'))
bagOfWords = vectorizer.fit(list2)
bagOfWords = vectorizer.transform(list2)
```

And it's working, but I want to stem a list of my words.

I've tried to make it this way

```
def tokeni(self,data):
        return [SnowballStemmer("english").stem(word) for word in data.split()]

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words=stopwords.words('english'), 
                             tokenizer=self.tokeni)
```

but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Update :
with tokenizer I have words like "oh...", "s-like..." , "knees,"
when without tokenizer I don't have any words with dots, commas, etc

Comment: What exactly does "it didn't work" mean? Please paste / describe the error you get / how you came to the conclusion that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a custom `preprocessor` which should work just as well, but retain the functionality of the `tokenizer`:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer

list2 = ["rain", "raining", "rainy", "rainful", "rains", "raining!", "rain?"]

def preprocessor(data):
        return " ".join([SnowballStemmer("english").stem(word) for word in data.split()])

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(preprocessor=preprocessor).fit(list2)
print vectorizer.vocabulary_

# Should print this:
# {'raining': 2, 'raini': 1, 'rain': 0}
```